# Is it necessary to wipe Flash-based drive using a multi-pass overwrite?

Tags: hard-drive, usb-flash-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there any data remanence issues with flash storage devices?](https://superuser.com/questions/190399/are-there-any-data-remanence-issues-with-flash-storage-devices)

Let's assume there is some sensitive material on the drive, that we wouldn't want to be on there even if we deleted.

From a file system perspective, we know that a "delete" is not always a full delete.  For that reason, it's important to overwrite all of the contents.

From a physical medium perspective, the older style disks were susceptible to having data recoverable, even after a single pass of all 0s or 1s.  As I understand it, this is the key reason to do multi-pass overwrites.

**Are Flash based drives susceptible to the same or similar forensic analysis of a single pass wipe?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there any data remanence issues with flash storage devices?](http://superuser.com/questions/190399/are-there-any-data-remanence-issues-with-flash-storage-devices) also see [Secure format of an SSD](http://superuser.com/questions/101465/secure-format-of-an-ssd/)

Comment: @techie007 That first link is a dup.  Thanks